# How to get apple's-website-like font style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, effects

Apple uses in it's web site a font with a kind of white shadow that make it look like a engraved/etched font. I found some tricks but it's always very limited. (btw the same effect is used [in this web site too](http://jonmsterling.com/2009/08/01/using-custom-delegates-in-objective-c.html) with different color)

What they do to get this font effect and make it work in all browsers. Someone know a script (javascript or even css stuff) to get the exact same effect ?
Thank you

Comment: Please give an example of the effect you're talking about.  I can't see anything special at the link you've provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about where you mean in the Apple site, but in the other link, it is achieved with the following CSS...

```
text-shadow: white -1px 1px;
```

As usual, the latest CSS stuff isn't so well supported by IE. I'd imagine < IE9 won't support this property.

It looks like you can use the Microsoft proprietary `filter` property to achieve something similar...

```
filter: Shadow(Color=#fffffff, Direction=0, Strength=1);
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the text-shadow property is not supported in all browsers,  as it's not part of the CSS 2.1 spec.

Comment: @kennis Not all browsers support CSS 2.1 either :) I'll make an edit.

Comment: Thank you it's really helpful, but how apple is able ti get it work evrywhere, i verified in IE6 it works just fine ! for example here : http://www.apple.com/iphone/  at  Shop Online / Visit Stor

Comment: @john Can you specify which portion of text you mean?

Comment: This one : "Order your iPhone 4 online and get it delivered to your door. It ships free and ready to use."  there is a small white effect arround the letters. It's more visible here : http://www.apple.com/iphone/ios4/  in the "Elegant and intuitive interface" paragraphe for example

Answer (score 3):

For the record, this doesn't work in all browsers. Not sure if it works in any version of IE, but in FF, Chrome, and Safari it should work fine.

The key CSS attribute is `text-shadow`. [Here's](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow.en.html) a quick ref

An example follow:

```
<style type="text/css">
   body {
     background-color: gray;
     color: black;
     text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px white;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did some sniffing around google and this is what apple "supposedly" uses...

```
h1 {

color:black;

font: 35px/50px "Lucida Grande", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;   

}
```